# Unable to deploy contract with params from another contract using Truffle

Tags: truffle

I have two Contracts - a contract with a single constructor argument (ContractB), and a launcher that deploys new instances (Launcher).

Using Truffle for testing how can I link the contracts without deploying contract B, given that contract B will return an error if deployed without prams

> Error: ContractB contract constructor expected 1 arguments, received 0

[Here is the link to Git repository](https://github.com/arashkiani/TruffleDeployContractFromAnotherContract)

deploy_contracts.js

```
var Launcher = artifacts.require("./Launcher.sol");
var ContractB = artifacts.require("./ContractB.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ContractB);
  deployer.link(ContractB, Launcher);
  deployer.deploy(Launcher);
};
```

Test File

```
var Launcher = artifacts.require("./Launcher.sol");

contract('Launcher', function(accounts) {
  it("Launcher Deploy", function() {
    return Launcher.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      console.log(instance)
    })
  });
});
```

Launcher.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./ContractB.sol";

contract launcher {

    function launch() public returns(address) {
        ContractB contractLocation = new ContractB(msg.sender);
        return(contractLocation);
    }
}
```

ContractB.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ContractB {
    address public owner;
    constructor(address addr) public {
    owner = addr;
  }

    function get() public view returns(address) {
        return(owner);
    }
}
```

[Here is the link to Git repository](https://github.com/arashkiani/TruffleDeployContractFromAnotherContract)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't deploy `ContractB` with migrations.

You should use a migration to deploy `Launcher`. There is no need to deploy `ContractB` because that's `Launcher`'s job.

Couple of things to watch out for:

- Make sure your event values have name 
  https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/494
- If truffle complains you may be able to deploy and link your contractB dependencies to launcher and leave the deployment of ContractB to Launcher
- Consider Truffle version 5 https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/1129#Bring-your-own-compiler

Comment: Hi Rob, Thank you for your answer but I was hoping we could keep the answer focused on truffle deployment rather than solidity code improvement

Comment: Consider rephrasing the question. It's unclear if you are focused on deployment or testing.

Comment: Done, hope it helps others )